# Extract values from a Json in bash

Tags: linux, shell, awk, sed, grep

I am trying my hand on shell scripting and was trying to extract values from a Json and store it into a variable to use it later. But I am unable to do so, have tried follow up lots of links and suggestion, probably I am doing something wrong.
Basically I am using curl to hit an url and from the response I am trying to extract the value of a **status** field .
I am trying the following lines,

`result=$(curl "http://localhost:9200/domains" | grep "status" | awk '{print $1 }')
echo "the result is" $result`

The curl command will fetch something like

```
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"index_not_found_exception","reason":"no such index","resource.type":"index_or_alias","resource.id":"domains","index_uuid":"_na_","index":"domains"}],"type":"index_not_found_exception","reason":"no such index","resource.type":"index_or_alias","resource.id":"domains","index_uuid":"_na_","index":"domains"},"status":404}
```

Any help in this regard is really appreciated. I know we can do it in jq or perl but I am looking for a solution using grep, sed or awk.

Thanks 
Ashit

Comment: Choose the right tool first. I suggest to use [jq](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jq/info).

Comment: grep, sed and awk are not made to operate on structured data like JSON, so anything you build based on these tools will be very brittle. It'll break, for example, when someone changes the formatting of the input data, and nobody expects their JSON tools to break when that happens. `jq .status` is the way to go here.

Answer (score 5):

Using `grep` and `awk`

```
result=$(curl "http://localhost:9200/domains" | \
    grep -o -E "\"status\":[0-9]+" | awk -F\: '{print $2}')
```

1. First, use `grep` to extract the pattern `status:[0-9]+`
2. Then, use `awk` to split the result by `:` and print the second field

Comment: You never need grep when you're using awk since awk can do anything useful that grep can do. Any `grep ... | awk ...` pipline can be written as a single awk command, e.g. your code could be written in GNU awk as `awk 'match($0,/\"status\":([0-9]+)/,a){print a[1]}'`

Answer (score 0):

When you are sure `status` won't pop up on a different place in your data, and always a numeric status, you can try

```
result=$(curl "http://localhost:9200/domains" | \
    sed -rn 's/.*,"status":([0-9]*).*/\1/p')
```

Use `-E` if there is no option `-r`

Answer (score 0):

Given that single sample of input, all you'd need is:

```
curl '...' | awk -F'[:}]' '{print $(NF-1)}'
```

If that's NOT all you need then edit your question to clarify your requirements and provide more truly representative sample input and expected output.